# ebtable NFLOG cause ARP request drop

Tags: netfilter, ebtables

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have two machines connected back to back with this ebtable rule setup:

`ebtables -A OUTPUT -p ARP --arp-op Request --nflog-group 100 -j DROP`

I have a process listening on netlink group 100. I have the following setup on both machines `/etc/network/interface` lets call this one **peer1**:

`auto e101-001-0
 iface e101-001-0 inet manual
auto bond100
 iface bond100 inet manual
  bond-slaves e101-001-0
  bond-mode 4
  bond-miimon 100
 iface bond100.100 inet manual
  vlan-raw-device bond100
auto br100
 iface br100 inet static
 bridge_ports bond100.100
 address 10.1.1.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0`

The **peer2** has the same setting except the ip address is `10.1.1.2`. When I try to send a ping from **peer1** to **peer2**, I get destination unreachable. Using `arp -n` I see it is not resolved. I used tcpdump and saw the ARP request  was made on **peer1** bridge but peer2 did not receive it on it's bridge. There are three ways I know of to get a ping across:

1. Erase the ebtable rule on **peer1**.
2. Don't use a bridge. This works fine if I just ping between physical interface.
3. Add this line to the etable rules above: `--nflog-range 32`. I can go as low as 22 and it will still work. It starts to fail around 17.

Anything lower than 32 seems to make it stop working. My questions are:

1. Is there a default nflog-range size if one is not set explicitly?
2. Is there a kernel config that affects the nflog-range size?

I know all this is part of the kernel so if it helps I'm using the default Debian Stretch kernel (Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4) (no special kernel config). **peer2** is running on a modified kernel and is known to be working. If I have two systems with the same specs as **peer2**, everything works fine, which leads me to believe it *maybe* a kernel config issue.

Thanks for reading.